# Need help narrowing down why SciPy curve_fit function "randomly" misbehaves

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am attempting to use the SciPy curve_fit function to fit a large amount of sets of data. Since this data is too large to individually look at and give initial guess parameters I don't have a `p0` input in the function. If anyone can suggest a method for my code to decipher a decent `p0` from the data prior to fitting, I would appreciate that.

The data is essentially the points plotted in the scatter plot, and the fitting equation is

```
f(x,AE,p,a) = 0 x < AE
f(x,AE,p,a) = a*(x - AE)^p
```

My code looks somewhat like this (I omitted parts that aren't that relevant to shorten it)

```py
def p_law(x, AE, p, a):
    y = np.piecewise(x, [x < AE, x >= AE],
                    [lambda x: 0, lambda x: a*(x - AE)**p])
    return y

a,b = x[y>0],y[y>0]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(p_law, a, b, method='lm', maxfev=2000000000)
fit0 = p_law(x, *popt)

ae = str(round(popt[0],2))
p  = str(round(popt[1],2))
s  = 'AE = ' + ae + '\np = ' + p
plt.plot(x,y,'.', label='Data')
plt.plot(x, fit0, label='Wanier Fitting of Data')
plt.text(12, 0.7*max(y), s)
plt.title(specie)
plt.savefig(savedir + str(specie) + '.png')
plt.close()
```

Note that x & y are previously defined as NumPy arrays of x & y values for the data. I know that having `maxfev=2000000000` is dumb and I shouldn't do that but if I don't a much larger portion of my data does not get fit.

Now here is what the fittings look like,

[image: This is an example of a great fit]
[image: This is an example of a terrible fit.]

Note, I have one fit working perfectly and the other not working at all but both are being done by the same code. How can I prevent this problem without looking at the data and giving a decent initial guess?

In fact any advice on improving this would help, Thanks!

EDIT: The data for the two fits shown above

28.1

```py
x = [ 8.4  8.6,  8.8,  9.0,   9.2,  9.4,  9.6,  9.8, 10.0,  10.2, 10.4, 10.6, 10.8, 11.0, 11.2, 11.4, 11.6, 11.8, 12.0,  12.2, 12.4, 12.6, 12.8, 13.0,  13.2, 13.4, 13.6, 13.8, 14.0,  14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 14.8, 15.0,  15.2, 15.4, 15.6, 15.8, 16. ]

y = [0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 8.73975e-17, 1.00835e-16, 2.16397e-16, 2.37897e-16, 5.32125e-16, 7.55940e-16, 9.25253e-16, 1.09048e-15, 1.41706e-15, 1.74418e-15, 1.83825e-15, 2.16612e-15, 2.59752e-15, 3.43269e-15, 4.37331e-15, 7.45244e-15]
```

43.1

```py
x = [ 8.4  8.6,  8.8,  9.0,   9.2,  9.4,  9.6,  9.8, 10.0,  10.2, 10.4, 10.6, 10.8, 11.0, 11.2, 11.4, 11.6, 11.8, 12.0,  12.2, 12.4, 12.6, 12.8, 13.0,  13.2, 13.4, 13.6, 13.8, 14.0,  14.2, 14.4, 14.6, 14.8, 15.0,  15.2, 15.4, 15.6, 15.8, 16. ]

y = [0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 1.15025e-17, 9.13750e-17, 4.66335e-16, 1.05489e-15, 1.32698e-15, 1.95650e-15, 2.78564e-15, 3.71681e-15, 4.50092e-15, 5.69825e-15, 6.41775e-15, 7.65873e-15, 8.22106e-15, 9.88463e-15, 1.08413e-14, 1.21321e-14, 1.26944e-14, 1.39555e-14, 1.56331e-14, 1.71234e-14]
```

Comment: Knowing that `f(x,AE,p,a) = 0  if x < AE` you can immediately add an initial guess for AE. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: Would you please post the data used for both of the plots, and the fitted parameters for the good fit?

Comment: @PéterLeéh as I understand the use of initial parameter estimates with scipy's curve_fit() routine, all parameters would need to have initial estimates and not only the parameter AE.

Comment: Is it possible in your work to change the units on the y data such that the magnitude of the y values is more similar to the magnitude of the x values?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I can scale the y-values for the fitting but I would then have to undo the scaling when plotting it. I will edit my post to include the data for those two fits, might take me a couple minutes to locate those two data sets.

Comment: @JamesPhillips the data was added to the question.

Comment: I was able to fit both data sets to the given function, but only if I did not use lambda and instead directly modeled the equation. Even then, with the given data as is, both were extremely sensitive to initial parameter estimates. Per your comment, I did not try scaling the data in any way.

Comment: @JamesPhillips What do you mean by `directly modeled the equation`?

Comment: I fit the all of the data in each data set to the equation "y = a*(x - AE)^p".

Comment: @JamesPhillips: Since you’re fitting only to the `y>0` part of the data, why even use `piecewise`?

Comment: @DavisHerring Great question! I originally was not fitting just the part `y>0` which is why I used `piecewise`. Ideally I would fit the entire data set, but fitting just `y>0` gives better results for some reason.

Comment: @Cavenfish: Probably because it avoids distracting the algorithm with points whose fit it can barely affect.  Since it appears that all the positive values are at the end, it doesn’t do any good to include the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This particular functional form is very easy to estimate from data this clean: take `AE` to be the last *x* for which *y*=0, and then perform a linear fit to the positive values in semi-log space.  Or, even simpler, use the last value and the one halfway between it and `AE` to solve for `a` and `p` with a minimum of noise.